# Django: Securing / encrypting stored files

Tags: django, security, encryption, file-storage

In a Django project, I want to keep user uploaded files secure on the server. Should this be done at the OS level (we are using ubuntu) or at the application level?

Encrypting at the application level will be easier to maintain. But, aside from some drawbacks like possible negative effect on performance, I am not even sure if this will have any point. If a hacker compromises the server, he will also have access to the encryption keys and how it is encrypted / decrypted.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

How you protect your data depends on what kinds of attacks you want to protect against.  Of course, you probably don't know how an attacker is most likely to compromise your system, unless there are certain threat models you're particularly trying to protect against, like say a rogue sysadmin.

The attacker might gain access to the OS that the web server is running on.  In this case, filesystem level encryption probably does you no good.  In fact file-system level encryption is probably only useful protection against somebody walking off with the physical server (which is a totally valid threat model).  However, if the files are encrypted with keys stored in the database, then an attacker who has access to the webserver OS but not the database is thwarted.

In contrast, an attacker might gain access to the database but not the OS, through a hole in your application.  I would expect this to be less likely since modern operating systems present huge and well-studied attack surfaces.

To protect your user's data against an attacker with full access to your servers is very difficult.  You need to encrypt the data with a key that your servers don't have.  This could be something like a password or a key stored in a user cookie.  The problem with all these schemes is that users can't be trusted to hold on to critical data like this -- they always want a way to reset their password if they forget.  In most cases, it's not realistic to protect data against an attacker with full access to your OS and your database.

So I'd choose what you're trying to protect against.  Personally, I'd expect an OS penetration to be most likely, and thus encrypt the files with keys that are stashed in a part of the database that is extra protected somehow.  The challenge here is that the OS has to store database login credentials (in `settings.py`) in order for the web app to function.  So try to keep those files as restricted as possible within the OS i.e. `chmod 600` on a user account that does as little else as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that if the key used to encrypt the files is stored on the server you don't get a whole lot of added security by encrypting the files.

However, if you use a key provided by the *user*, then you do get some security. For example, if you store the encryption key in a cookie, then it will only be available for the duration of each request. I don't believe this will create any *new* security issues (if an attacker can steal the cookie, they can also steal the user's session), and it will make it much harder for an attacker to access files belonging to users who aren't currently online.

If you're really paranoid, you could do what 1Password does, and send encrypted data back to the browser, which can decrypt it with JavaScript encryption routines…